# undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, libgosu

I can't work out how to fix it so it takes ten away from the health class variable, as it says that it is an error.

```
/home/will/Code/Rubygame/objects.rb:61:in `attacked': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./main.rb:140:in `update'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.10.8/lib/gosu/patches.rb:140:in `tick'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/gosu-0.10.8/lib/gosu/patches.rb:140:in `tick'
    from ./main.rb:197:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code in main:

```
def update
    @player.left if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbA
    @player.right if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbD
    @player.up if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbW
    @player.down if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbS
    if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbK 
        @player.shot if @player_type == "Archer" or @player_type == "Mage"
        if @object.collision(@xshot, @yshot) == true
            x, y, health = YAML.load_file("Storage/info.yml")
            @object.attacked #LINE 140
        end
    end

end
```

And here is where the @object.attacked leads to:

```
 def attacked
    puts "attacked"
    @health -= 10 #LINE 61
    @xy.insert(@health)
    File.open("Storage/info.yml", "w") {|f| f.write(@xy.to_yaml) }
    @xy.delete_at(2)
    if @health == 0
        @dead = true
    end
end
```

And the yaml file if needed:

```
   ---
   - 219.0
   - 45.0
   - 100.0
```

I tried to put .to_i after the @health like this:

```
   @health.to_i -= 10
```

But it just brings up another error saying:

```
   undefined method `to_i=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I think your issue is actually `x, y, health = YAML.load_file("Storage/info.yml")` I am assuming this should be `@x, @y, @health = YAML.load_file("Storage/info.yml")` instance variables rather than local variables.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that `@health == nil` in your `attacked` method. You need to initialize this value somewhere! Usually this would be in the aptly-named `initialize` method of your class. Alternatively going on the code that you have provided so far, if when somebody is attacked for the first time you want to set the `@health` instance variable to a default value you could change it to:

```
def attacked
  @health ||= 100 # or whatever
  puts "attacked"
  @health -= 10 #LINE 61
  @xy.insert(@health)
  File.open("Storage/info.yml", "w") {|f| f.write(@xy.to_yaml) }
  @xy.delete_at(2)
  if @health == 0
    @dead = true
  end
end
```

---

Note: the `||=` syntax is ruby's conditional assignment operator – it means 'set `@health` to 100 unless @health is already defined.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @omnikron, your `@health` is uninitialized, hence `-=` throws an exception when trying to subtract from `nil`. If we go with initialize method instead, I imagine your object class looking like:

```
Class Object
  attr_accessor :health

  def initialize
    @health = 100
  end
end

def attacked
  puts "attacked"
  @object.health -= 10 #LINE 61
  @xy.insert(@object.health)
  File.open("Storage/info.yml", "w") {|f| f.write(@xy.to_yaml) }
  @xy.delete_at(2)
  if @health == 0
    @dead = true
  end
end
```

Comment: On a different topic, using `Object` as a class name is going to cause you some interesting problems down the line, because every single ruby object inherits from the `Object` class! So this will overwrite the initialize method for _every single ruby object_. You can try this in irb, where you will see that the above code prints `"warning: redefining Object#initialize may cause infinite loop"`